# Firebase Fetch All Data on Path Returns only First Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

In my react native Expo app at `componentWillMount` I want to fetch all data in a path at Firebase database

```
  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true, uid: user.uid });
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/memories`)
          .once("value").then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            console.log(snapshot);
            /* a dispatch from redux rematch */
            this.props.addMemory(snapshot.val());
          });
      } else {...}
    });
  }
```

but `console.log` shows that only the first object is returned.
is it the correct `event` name I am calling? is it the right approach for getting all data when app starts?

Comment: .once("value").then(

Comment: @spitson where is the problem? .once('value')  is not returning all data?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
.once("value").then(snapshot => {
```

to this:

```
.on("value").then(snapshot => {
```

---

`once`

Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: Thank you, it helped for other parts but was not the answer. actually now the app is working with .once('value') at componentWillMount. I do not know how and why but it just works.